# FTPS or HTTPS - which is the better way to transfer big files from hundreds of clients to server using Java?

Tags: file, https, upload, ftps

Parameters for evaluation:
- 1000 connections from the client (connection may be slow in some cases)
- Multithreaded upload when connection is good (of the same file, or different files)
- Ability to resume an upload from the client
- SSL/TLS support (in case of FTPS and HTTPS)
- Load balancer in front of the server

The client would be written in Java and so requires a Java interface to the FTPS/HTTPS client.

So far, I have taken a look at Apache Commons FTPS/HTTP clients, Apache MINA and Apache Camel. There was a comment in SO that Commons FTPS client does not resume uploads - is this really so (the API seems to support it though).

Comment: You should probably clarify the SSL/TLS criterion.  SFTP is part of the SSH protocol suite, which is different from SSL.  However, they are both secure when used correctly.

Comment: EDIT: updated question to qualify support for SSL/TLS

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for massive perfs, you should try to write your own protocol on top of SSL (using Apache MINA or Netty or plain NIO)